# detect argument was already specified (argparse)

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

When using argparse module when we specify optional argument we can specify it multiple times, e.g

```
my_app --arg a --arg b --arg c --arg d
```

The final value in resulting `Namespace` is the value of last specified argument in command-line ("d" in example). Can this situation be detected? I want to somehow notify user about this behaviour.

I can make my custom `Action`, but I do not want to redefine all standard actions, e.g. `store_true`. It will be cool to somehow wrap standard `add_argument(...)` function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may not be a good idea to do this, just so you know. Many command line tools intentionally allow the same argument to be specified multiple times, allowing a switch set by some earlier alias or what have you to be replaced; for example, if you `alias gcc='gcc -O3'`, you can run `gcc -O0` to override; the final command line is `gcc -O3 -O0`, but `gcc` is perfectly fine with that, and uses the last specified value.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it with creating your own Action, but here is how you can do without an Action, by using the `action='append'` argument to `add_argument`:

```
import argparse
import sys
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--arg', action='append')
print("0 options:", p.parse_args([]))
print("1 option:", p.parse_args("--arg a".split()))
print("2 options:", p.parse_args("--arg a --arg b".split()))
print("3 options:", p.parse_args("--arg a --arg b --arg c".split()))
print()
args = p.parse_args()
if args.arg:
    if len(args.arg) > 1:
        sys.exit("Option --arg specified multiple times!")
```

Running the above with no arguments:

```
$ python3 par.py
0 options: Namespace(arg=None)
1 option: Namespace(arg=['a'])
2 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b'])
3 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Running with 1 argument:

```
$ python3 par.py --arg a
0 options: Namespace(arg=None)
1 option: Namespace(arg=['a'])
2 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b'])
3 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Running with 2 (or more) arguments gets you to `sys.exit()`:

```
$ python3 par.py --arg a --arg b                                      
0 options: Namespace(arg=None)
1 option: Namespace(arg=['a'])
2 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b'])
3 options: Namespace(arg=['a', 'b', 'c'])

Option --arg specified multiple times!
```